# How to find the admin users in a space in confluence

Tags: c#, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am looking for a (preferably) REST API to find the admin users in a space. The space I am getting from a REST call as below:

/rest/api/space.

I trying to make the call to the API using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns the quests:

URL:  /rpc/json-rpc/confluenceservice-v2/getSpacePermissionSet
Body:  ["","SETSPACEPERMISSIONS"]